# opencv android java matrix submatrix (ROI Region of Interest)

Tags: android, opencv, submatrix

I've `mRgba Matrix and a Rect r` (something recognized in the frame)

I want a sub-matrix of this part of the frame which is defined by the `Rect r.`

when I use it like this:

`sub = mRgba.submat(r);`

I get the right sub-matrix, but I've a problem with the next steps, I want to change this part of the frame and then copy it back to the original.

*For example:*

```
 Imgproc.cvtColor(sub, sub, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 1); //make it gray
 Imgproc.cvtColor(sub, sub, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4); //change to rgb
```

How can I copy this changed sub-matrix back to the original.
or how can I get/create a Mask same size as mRgba with all zeros except the Rect r part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub = mRgba.submat(r);

Imgproc.cvtColor(sub, sub, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 1); //make it gray
Imgproc.cvtColor(sub, sub, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4); //change to rgb

sub.copyTo(mRgba.submat(r));
```

ok this seems to do the trick :) it copies the changed subpicture/matrix back in the region of the source.. (what is normally done with setROI and copyto)

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind, if you want to copy two submats `a`, `b` from different sources `A`, `B` it's important that `A` and `B` have the same type (e.g `CV_32F`)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work as you expected because it is impossible to change number of colors in-place. You need a temporary matrix to make it work:

```
Mat tmp;
Imgproc.cvtColor(sub, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY); //make it gray
Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, sub, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA); //change to rgb
```

Comment: hi.. thx for your answer.. actually that seems to be no problem and/or changes nothing.

is the only way to make a mask step-by-step with for loops?

Comment: sub.copyTo(mRgba.submat(r));

ok this seems to do the trick :) it copies the changed subpicture/matrix back in the region of the original image.